# Guide in solving spoj GiveAway

Tags: binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I was unable to solve the problem Spoj Give away after thinking for a while and searching for help I came to know that it involves AVL Tree + Segement Tree . Since I haven't used this data Structure yet a detail explanation of Working code and the approach is much encouraged.
Link : http://www.spoj.com/problems/GIVEAWAY/

Answer (score 2):

In SPOJ GIVEAWAY, the problem requires you to address a lot of *queries* and whenever we have to handle more than one *queries*, **SQRT decomposition** technique or **Segment tree** comes forward. I would suggest you to solve the problem using **SQRT decomposition** method. If you're new to both the methods, you can watch tutorials or some documentation on the internet. I'm providing some links I hope it'll help you ;)

[SQRT Decomposition](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sqrt-square-root-decomposition-technique-set-1-introduction/)

[Segment Tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/)